# bash - add a variable to binary inside string

Tags: linux, bash, curl

So I have a curl command in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -s 'http://eamorr.com/?' -H 'Host: eamorr.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0' --data-binary $'-----------------------------1024109981087242139340277850\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="target"\r\n\r\n90210\r\n-----------------------------102410998108724213934027785--\r\n'
```

This works fine for me.

Now, instead of 90210, I would like to try 90211

```
#!/bin/bash

postcode=90211

curl -s 'http://eamorr.com/?' -H 'Host: eamorr.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0' --data-binary $'-----------------------------1024109981087242139340277850\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="target"\r\n\r\n'$postcode'\r\n-----------------------------102410998108724213934027785--\r\n'
```

This won't work...

I think it's something to do with the $ in front of the --data-binary string? I tried dropping the $, but it wouldn't work.

I tried $(postcode), etc. to no avail

Comment: But the solution was nothing to do with quotes. The solution (as @choroba identified) was to make the second part of the string C-style (which I overlooked). You should therefore remove your down-vote.

Comment: Unfortunatley, I'm not allowed to remove my downvote unless the question is edited.  My aplogies.

Comment: Hi @tipleee. I understand. Thank you for being so honest. I'm sorry if I came across aggressive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you now wrongly quote what follows the postcode. `\r\n` is not interpreted in single quotes, you need `$'\r\n'`:

```
...'$postcode$'\r\n...
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem!!! I was at this for nearly an hour. A good spot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

postcode="90211"

curl -s 'http://eamorr.com/?' -H 'Host: eamorr.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0' --data-binary $"-----------------------------1024109981087242139340277850\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"target\"\r\n\r\n$postcode\r\n-----------------------------102410998108724213934027785--\r\n"
```

using quotation is a good practice, and `"'$postcode'"` is actually `'90211'` not `90211`